# Accurate timer based processing implementation using condition variable

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, condition-variable

I need a thread to perform processing every one second accurately. Suppose if the worker thread is busy on some operation that takes more than one second, I want the worker thread to miss the 1s expiry notification and perform the processing in the next cycle.

I am trying to implement this using two threads. One thread is a worker thread, another thread sleeps for one second and notifies the worker thread via condition variable.

Code is shown below

Worker thread

```
    while(!threadExit){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        // Block until a signal is received
        condVar_.wait(lock, [this](){return (threadExit || performProc);)});

        if(threadExit_){
            break;
        }

        // Perform the processing
        ..............
     }
```

Timer thread

```
    while(!threadExit)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            performProc= false;
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

        if(threadExit){
            break;
        }

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            performProc= true;
        }
        condVar.notify_one();
    }
```

Please note the variable threadExit is set by the main thread under the mutex lock and notified to worker thread. The timer thread can see this flag when it wakes up(which should be fine for my implementation)

Do you think **performProc** may set to false again before the worker thread sees it as true? If yes, can you please throw some light on how to tackle this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless `threadExit` is `atomic`, the code exhibits undefined behavior (race condition). All accesses to `threadExit` must be protected by a mutex, so also reads in `while(!threadExit)` and `if(threadExit)...`.

But there's no need to do any of this. You can run everything in the same thread if you use [`sleep_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) (and a steady clock) instead of `sleep_for`.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::literals;

void do_work() {
    std::cout << "Work @ " << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    while (true) {
        auto t = ceil<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + 600ms);
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(t);
        do_work();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Work @ 2022-03-04 09:56:51.0148904
Work @ 2022-03-04 09:56:52.0134687
Work @ 2022-03-04 09:56:53.0198704
Work @ 2022-03-04 09:56:54.0010437
Work @ 2022-03-04 09:56:55.0148975
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I need a behavior wherein when do_work takes more than 1 second, it should miss that interval and do_work needs to be called in the n+1 second. To illustrate this:-
  1               do_work()
  2               do_work() --> Assume it is taking more than one second
  3                --> nothing no operation, I want to consider this as a miss
                    --> Assume do_work completes before 4th second
  4               do_work()

Comment: Yes, if do_work() can take longer, then just sleep to the next full second. See my update.

Comment: Assume do_work finished at 56,900ms. It will add to 56,900 + 600ms = 57,500. The sleep will be then performed till end of 58th second, correct?

Comment: Yes, you can play with the 600ms value to find the most optimal value for your case. 600ms determines the minimal delay before the next run.

Comment: Ok. However, In this case I would need the do_work to be executed again at 57th second rather than 58th second. I might then need to probably calculate the time consumed by do_work and adjust the sleep_until accordingly. Thanks for your answer!